# SVN server setup on ubuntu small query

Tags: svn, ubuntu, repository, subversive, svn-server

I had setup the Subversion repository on my server.
When I add any file to my working copy and commit it, it says committed successfully. Now when i access repository location from url it shows me those files there but when i log in via SSH and look in the repository folder the file is not there.

For example: 
on following url i see the list of all folder and file in my repository

http://ec2-23-23-213-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myproject/

But from SSH when i look in my /www/myproject/ i find only following files

README.txt, conf, db, format, hooks,  locks,  project1
Where "project1" is my initial import.

Is it like this only or i had made any mistake in setting up SVN.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN stores files, differences, properties, revisions, etc. in a database. Don't expect to find the files directly under the repository folder.

If you can access the repository via your SVN client, and if everything runs as expected, then your server is going well.

Comment: Thanks for replay JB Nizet ...